# Write on browser console with Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to write on the developer console from the browser to create some test with Webdriver but I'm not being able to do it, is there any way to execute some scripts and get the retrieved information from it?

Comment: Most webdriver versions are able to execute javascript inside the browser. If you execute `console.log("...")` that way it will output to the browsers developer console. Which webdriver are you using?

Comment: I could do it, I only had to do an javascript execution with the string